# Asp.net C# Fileupload and Access Interaction

Tags: c#, ms-access, interop, file-upload

I'm building a webapp that needs to interact with a Access Database.  The Access database is about 200 megs and I don't want to upload the entire thing...just the contents of one table.  So far, I've used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access in the past on a desktop app but when I tried this on a webapp there is some cryptic permission issues on the web server(I think) that need to be ferreted out.

As far as I understand it I can 
1 - upload the entire database and select the data 
2 - I can use interop and figure out the permission issues

is there a 3 or 4 option?

Thanks guys.

Comment: why would you have to upload the access database? isn't it already on the server??

Comment: no...it's on a a different server,

Comment: then I still don't understand why you would want to upload it somewhere

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking...I have a webapp on a webserver and an Access database on another server.  I'd like the user to be able to browse to the database, have a list of the tables displayed to the user, have the user select the table they want to process and go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the access file doesn't matter as long as it is accessible local or through the network and the NETWORK account of the webserver (if it is a Win2K3 or higher server otherwise it's the ASP.NET account) has access to that location.
So no need to download or upload anything.
Also... the fact that your back-end is dealing with an access database shouldn't be visible or be of any concern to the client...

OTOH if you are looking for a solution to "manage a database through a web interface", then maybe it's better to look at something like [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asp-ent-man/)... (It's for sql server, but migrating from access to sql server isn't that big an issue ;-)

If you want to code it yourself, i think [this](http://aspalliance.com/542) post can come in handy.
No need to interop, just use an OleDbConnection with the right connectionstring.

Comment: so, map a drive and do a regular access connection string.

I'm taking the clients highly denormalized access database, normalizing the data and then inserting this data into SQL.  

The minimum requirments dictate that we are able to create reports for the clients client.  I wanted to know if my sql database design was "good enough" to support the creation of these reports, so at first I'm only bring in a small amount of the data located in one table.

Next is the web interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understood your problem but maybe you could upload the table data using a CSV file, then parse every line and use a SQL query to INSERT this data the Access database.

Comment: this is what I'm going to do...create a csv and parse that out...I was trying to remove any chance the user could mess this up.